# How can I easily install arm-elf-gcc on OS X?

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, arm, gnu

Please let me know if this should be on Server Fault...

I've got some code I want to compile which requires `arm-elf-gcc`. I'm not an embedded programmer, so all this is new to me. My development machine is a Mac and I use fink pretty often, so I'd love to be able to install it that way. However, fink doesn't know of any package with that name. I see that [gnuarm.org](http://ww.gnuarm.org) has some binaries for OS X but their packages seem to also include a bunch of stuff (e.g. gcc) I already have. Am I correct in believing that I [need to install](http://www.jstuber.net/lego/nxt-programming/arm-toolchain.html) `binutils`, `newlib` and a file called [t-arm-elf](http://gnuarm.com/t-arm-elf)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) supports arm-elf-gcc.

```
$ port search arm-elf
arm-elf-binutils @2.20.51.0.2 (cross, devel)
    FSF Binutils for arm-elf cross development

arm-elf-gcc @4.3.2 (cross, devel)
    gcc cross-compilers for arm-elf, with newlib runtime library.

arm-elf-gcc3 @3.4.6 (cross, devel)
    gcc 3.x cross-compilers for arm-elf, with newlib runtime library.

Found 3 ports.
```

Once you install MacPorts, all it would take is:

```
$ sudo port install arm-elf-gcc
```

Comment: I've never tried fink, but macports puts everything in /opt/local and updates PATH and MANPATH environment variables. I don't think it has any other impact on the system.

Comment: I seem to have problems with it on snow leopard
constantly gives me architecture errors on build

Comment: I had the same problem on Snow Leopard a while ago.  Running 'port selfupdate' and then retrying the install of arm-elf-gcc worked, so they must have fixed it.